# win7 changed password and encrypted files are not accessible

Tags: windows-7, encryption

I did a reinstall of windows after I was having some issue with updates not working and the winsxs folder was getting huge and eating up about 14gb of my 80gb ssd. I thought I decrypted all the files prior to the uninstall but I guess I missed some. I know the password. Is there any way I can get the old files decrypted?

Comment: What did you encrypt it with? BitLocker? Did you export your personal certificate before changing the password?

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/462971/ive-lost-access-to-my-encrypted-files/463036#463036

Comment: I guess it is bitlocker or efs. I clicked on the encrypt check in the properties menu. I have a backup of my user profile from before the reinstall so would I be able to get the cert from there?

Comment: Is the certificate encrypted itself? If so, then no

Comment: nope it was just a documents folder with sensitive stuff like taxes and such not the whole drive. that folder was on a different drive actually.

Comment: If you can access the certificate in an *unencrypted* manner, you can reimport it and read your files

Comment: thanks, I am restoring the backup from a cloud service, and its several gigs, so its gonna take a while. do you know where I can find the cert file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8983/discussion-between-luke-and-john-s)

Comment: Did you solve it? If yes (and you remember how), put it on an answer so other can know how you did it.